# How to Minus 2nd row value from the 1st row in same HTML table

Tags: php, html

I'm struggling with a PHP Code, and I have no clue how to solve this. I have two columns with timestamps on which I've ordered by desc in my Html table which I'm generating with PHP code.

I need to find out the differences between the 2nd row StateEndTime and the 1st-row StateStarTtime nd so on and display this in a new row/column. The final table should look like this :

```
ID          Type         StateStarTtime    StateEndTime   Min Difference

xxx         YYY          03:57             03:59          00:02
xxx         ZZZ          03:53             03:55          00:04
xxx         ZZZ          03:46             03:49
```

Below is the PHP code in my index file

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
  <tr>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['Username'];?></td>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['StateStarttime'];?></td>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['StateEndtime'];?></td>
      <?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: What difference you want to find? Time difference in seconds? How should the difference look? i:s?

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php or perform your date calc in your SQL query https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Comment: @Wr1t3r I want to find the minute difference it can look 00:02

Comment: @Scuzzy I need to perform the calculation in PHP. I only have the view access of the database I'm using below query to fetch the data "SELECT * FROM time WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= Timestamp AND EmpID='".$valueToSearch."' ORDER BY `time`.`Timestamp` DESC"

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
    $lasttime = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
    <tr>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['Username'];?></td>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['StateStarttime'];?></td>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['StateEndtime'];?></td>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo ($row['StateStarttime'] - $lasttime);?></td>
      <?php 
$lasttime = $row['StateStarttime'];
endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this I suggest first creating array with results and than use this array to generate table. Code isn't tested. Let me know if it's working.

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++): ?>
    <?php
    $datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('i:s', $results[$i]['StateStarttime']);
    $datetime2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('i:s', $results[$i+1]['StateEndtime']);

    if($datetime2)
        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2)->format('%I:%S');
    else
        $interval = 'unknown';

    ?>
    <tr>
        <td align="Center"><?php echo $results[$i]['id'];?></td>
        <td align="Center"><?php echo $results[$i]['Username'];?></td>
        <td align="Center"><?php echo $results[$i]['StateStarttime']; ?></td>
        <td align="Center"><?php echo $results[$i]['StateEndtime']; ?></td>
        <td align="Center"><?php echo $interval; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: I'm Getting 
Notice: Undefined index: StateStarttime 
Notice: Undefined index: StateEndtime
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function diff() on boolean

Comment: please add <?php var_dump($results); ?> after first row and let me know what it displays.

Comment: array(4) { [0]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(6) "624121" [1]=> string(6) "304222" [2]=> string(10) "02-01-2019" [3]=> string(4) "user" [4]=> string(8) "NIPL-764" [5]=> string(4) "Idle" [6]=> string(1) "1" [7]=> string(5) "11:03" [8]=> string(5) "11:03" [9]=> string(19) "2019-02-01 11:03:57" }

Comment: [1]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(6) "624120" [1]=> string(6) "304222" [2]=> string(10) "02-01-2019" [3]=> string(4) "user" [4]=> string(8) "NIPL-764" [5]=> string(4) "Idle" [6]=> string(1) "2" [7]=> string(5) "11:01" [8]=> string(5) "11:03" [9]=> string(19) "2019-02-01 11:03:51" }

Comment: [2]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(6) "624086" [1]=> string(6) "304222" [2]=> string(10) "02-01-2019" [3]=> string(4) "user" [4]=> string(8) "NIPL-764" [5]=> string(6) "Active" [6]=> string(2) "15" [7]=> string(5) "10:46" [8]=> string(5) "11:01" [9]=> string(19) "2019-02-01 11:01:57" }

Comment: [3]=> array(10) { [0]=> string(6) "623764" [1]=> string(6) "304222" [2]=> string(10) "02-01-2019" [3]=> string(5) "user1" [4]=> string(8) "NIPL-887" [5]=> string(6) "Active" [6]=> string(1) "3" [7]=> string(5) "10:44" [8]=> string(5) "10:46" [9]=> string(19) "2019-02-01 10:47:02" } }

Comment: Edited code again and it's tested now. If array is correct, it will display correct results. Let me know if it works for you. If yes, mark my answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: I'm Getting 
Notice: Undefined variable: results
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Answer (score 0):

Please create method common with 2 param , return string Difference with suggestions like below

```
<?php
$checkTime = strtotime('00:03:55');
echo 'Check Time : '.date('H:i:s', $checkTime);
echo '<hr>';

$loginTime = strtotime('00:04:58');
$diff = $checkTime - $loginTime;
echo 'Login Time : '.date('H:i:s', $loginTime).'<br>';
echo ($diff < 0)? 'Late!' : 'Right time!'; echo '<br>';
echo 'Time diff in sec: '. gmdate("i:s", abs($diff));

echo '<hr>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would parse the time from $row['StateStarttime'] and $row['StateEndtime'] into 2 separate variables using strtotime and then print the difference. Something like:

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):
   $startTime = strtotime($row['StateStarttime']);
   $endTime = strtotime($row['StateEndtime']);
;?>
  <tr>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['Username'];?></td>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['StateStarttime'];?></td>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['StateEndtime'];?></td>
      <td align="Center"><?php echo $endTime - $startTime;?></td>
 <?php endwhile;?>
```

Note: The code above is just and example so it isn't tested.

Good luck,
Teo