# Jquery or JavaScripts to add calculation column in html table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm Generating an HTML table with PHP and Mysql query (Table look like this https://ibb.co/2k8XbbZ)

```
DB ID   EmpID   Date        Username    Computername    State   Minutesatstate  Statestarttime  Stateendtime        Timestamp
704634  303836  02-06-2019  user        PC-818          Idle    2               13:44           13:46               2019-02-06 13:46:46
704599  303836  02-06-2019  user        PC-818          Active  16              13:28           13:44               2019-02-06 13:44:46
704340  303836  02-06-2019  user        NIPL-1220       Active  2               13:27           13:28               2019-02-06 13:28:48
704313  303836  02-06-2019  user        PC-818          Active  13              13:15           13:27               2019-02-06 13:27:31
```

I Want to add another column with Jquery or Javascripts to subtract Statestarttime column of 1st row with Stateendtime column of 2nd row to find out the time difference

example of expected results

```
StateStarTtime    StateEndTime   Min Difference 

03:57             03:58          00:03
03:53             03:54          00:04
03:46             03:49          null
```

I'm able to find so many example and help for subtracting StateStarTtime from StateEndTime in the first row but i want to subtract  1st row cell value of StateStarTtime from 2nd row cell value of StateEndTime to find the Minute Difference.

I'm beginner in HTML and PHP but completely new to JS/JQ so any direction on how i can do this is much appreciated. below are the PHP and HTML codes snippet i'm using. let me know if you want complete code.

```
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>

            <tr>
                <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['EmpID'];?></td>
                <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['Date'];?></td>
                <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['Username'];?></td>
                <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['Computername'];?></td>
                <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['State'];?></td>
                <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['MinutesatState'];?></td>
                <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['StateStarttime'];?></td>
                <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['StateEndtime'];?></td>
                <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['Timestamp'];?></td>


            </tr>
            <?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: If you';re generating the table form PHP data it would make *far* more sense to do the calculation there instead of in client-side JS.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions on how I can do that.
I have also asked the Q. about it but not able to get it working correctly (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54474772/how-to-minus-2nd-row-value-from-the-1st-row-in-same-html-table/54475005#54475005)

Answer (score 1):

try using storing StateStarTtime and StateEndTime in array using another loop and then
calculate it as follow because you cant get value of next row in single loop

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
    <?php $startTime[] =  $row['StateStarttime'];?>
    <?php $endTime[] = $row['StateEndtime'];?>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php 
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
        <tr>
            <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
            <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['EmpID'];?></td>
            <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['Date'];?></td>
            <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['Username'];?></td>
            <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['Computername'];?></td>
            <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['State'];?></td>
            <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['MinutesatState'];?></td>
            <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['StateStarttime'];?></td>
            <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['StateEndtime'];?></td>
            <td align="Center"><?php echo $row['Timestamp'];?></td>
            //your calculation goes here like diff



            <td align="Center">
               <?php 
                   $mycalc = ($startTime[$i] - endTime[$i+1]);   
                    echo $mycalc;
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        $i++;
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: I'm getting Fatal error: Cannot use temporary expression in write context

Comment: I'm getting Fatal error: Cannot use temporary expression in write context (in 2nd line     <?php startTime[] =  $row['StateStarttime'];?>)

Comment: sorry! there is typo error please check my edited answer

Comment: Now i'm able to see the page but the table is not been created I've also fixed the missing $ in $endTime[$i+1]) but no luck

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it in PHP by using it

```
 <td align="Center"><?php echo($row['StateEndtime'] - $row['StateStarTtime ']) ?></td>
```

Comment: This will give me the Minute Difference of StateStarTtime and StateEndtime in the same row i want to subtract 1st row cell value of StateStarTtime from 2nd row cell value of StateEndTime and so on to find the Minute Difference.